# Remove css attribute as ajax reponse is executed

Tags: javascript, jquery

First I have a hidden div

```
  <div id="save" class="form-group hidden ">
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" id="btnUu" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want to remove `hidden` attribute when my ajax call is executed:

Ajax:

```
function GetSchoolMan() {
    debugger;
    currentId = 0;

    try {
        $(function () {
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: "get",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "/LogWaste/GetForEdit",
                data: { manifest: manifest },
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: onGetModulLogWasteSuccess,
                error: function (response) {
                    ErrorMessage("Error", GetTextError(response));
                }
            });
        });
    } catch (e) {
        ErrorMessage("Error", e.message);
    }
}
```

I try to add `$('#save').removeAttr('hidden');` at the top of my ajax call like

```
function GetSchoolMan() {
    debugger;
    currentId = 0;
    $('#save').removeAttr('hidden');
    try {...
```

but it didn´t work, how can I make it work? Regards

Comment: `class="form-group hidden "` `hidden` is clearly a **class**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no attribute `hidden` on `#save`. You have a css class. Use this to remove it

```
$('#save').removeClass('hidden');
```

Comment: Totally true. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is correct, you are currently using a class, not an attribute.  If you want to use the "hidden" attribute instead of CSS, then the jQuery you need is:

```
$('#save').show();     //show element
$('#save').hide();     //hide element
$('#save').toggle();   //toggle element visibility
```